# Inserting a random number into an array with sorted order C++

Tags: c++, arrays, random, variable-assignment, sortedlist

Hello I am trying to make an array that inserts a random number but when it does, the array stays in a maintained order. For example if the array contained 10 20 30 and the random number was 11 the function would put it after 10 and move 20 and 30 down the list. Here are the requirements for the function.

- insertNumber inserts a  given random number into the array and maintains order.
- The data array contains integers in sorted order from index 0 through size - 2.
- randomNum is the integer to be inserted
- data is the array containing sorted integers
- size is the total number of elements which the array can hold

Here is my code so far. I am getting nothing in my output.

```
#include"utils.h" 

void insertNumber(int randomNum, int data[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        randomNum = data[i];
        if (randomNum > data[i] && i < size - 2)
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j--)
            {
                data[i+1] = data [i];
                i--;
            } 
        }
        data[i] = randomNum;
    }
}

void display(int data[],  int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; size < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << data[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need an array, or could you also use an ordered container?

Comment: the 5th line is completely wrong. The if condition is never met and therefor you array will always remain the same.

Comment: May be a typo but "size < 10"? I think there should be i < size

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::lower_bound` algorithm to have an insertion position, and an `std::vector` container to shift the elements with the `insert` method

Answer (score 1):

You could use BinarySearch to search your array and see if the random number exists. If it does exist than you can insert near the existing one.

```
void binary_search(int A[], int key, int imin, int imax)
{
  if (imax < imin):
    // Insert key as the next element after imax
  else
    {
      // calculate midpoint to cut set in half
      int imid = midpoint(imin, imax);

      // three-way comparison
      if (A[imid] > key)
        // key is in lower subset
        binary_search(A, key, imin, imid-1);
      else if (A[imid] < key)
        // key is in upper subset
        binary_search(A, key, imid+1, imax);
      else
        // key has been found so insert it after imax
    }
}
```

- code taken from Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm *

Comment: That is great to know. I don't think I can use it in my assignment though because we are only allowed to use the two functions I have given so it much be in the insertNumber function.

Comment: @KaylaBianchi Two functions with or without main? If without u can use binary_search() and void insert(int A[], int length, int key, int position)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be a better way of implementing it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> randomInts;
    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        randomInts.push_back((rand()%30)+1); //Inserts random numbers 1-30.

    std::sort(randomInts.begin(),randomInts.end());
    for(auto i : randomInts)
        std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Output: `3 6 9 13 14 16 19 20 25 30`

Comment: It probably would be but my college professor wants only an array in that function and doesn't want us to change anything he did in main.

Comment: @KaylaBianchi is he trying to make you implement a bubble sort?

Comment: No just sort after inserting a number to make in in numerical order in the array.

Comment: @KaylaBianchi that's called a [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) then.

Answer (score -1):

Insert your random number after you find the element greater than it, inside your function

```
for( i =0; i<size ;i++)
{
    if(data[i] > randomNumber)
    {
         valueToPush = data[i];
         data[i] = randomNumber;
         randomNumber = valueToPush;
    }
}
data[size] = randomNumber
```

Comment: This is correct but suboptimal. This algorithm runs in O(n) time, while it can run in O(log n) time if you are using binary search, which is possible since the array is sorted.